# Query Wikipedia data page

Tags: python, web-crawler, wikipedia

I have trouble understanding wikipedia API.

I have **isolated** a link, by processing json that I got as a response after sending a request to **http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php**

Assuming that I got the following [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_Aniston), how do I get access to information like date of birth, etc.

I'm using python. I tried doing a

```
import urllib2,simplejson
search_req = urllib2.Request(direct_url_to_required_wikipedia_page)
response = urllib2.urlopen(search_req)
```

I have tried reading the api. But, I can't figure out how to extract data from specific pages.

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import simplejson

url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'
values = {'action' : 'query',
          'prop' : 'revisions',
          'titles' : 'Jennifer_Aniston',
          'rvprop' : 'content',
          'format' : 'json'}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
json = response.read()
```

Variable json is the json of the wikipedia page. You can now parse it with simplejson or whatever...

Answer (score 3):

Go to [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API). It's better organized, and friendly for humans :-).

Answer (score 1):

You won't get information like date of birth from the API, at least not directly. The best you can do is to get the code of the page (or rendered HTML) and parse that to get the information you need.

As an alternative, you might want to look at [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/About).

Comment: I know, I can't get that information directly. I tried directly downloading the page, it gave me a 403 error. I was clueless. Thanks anyways.

Comment: If you get 403, read [Wikimedia User-Agent policy](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy).